# Dapper ensure that query succeeded best practice

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I want to use `Dapper` into my WebApi Project. I Have a method for creating database from query:

```
    public async Task<bool> CreateDatabase()
    {
        var connection = _connection.GetOpenConnection();

        bool created = await connection.ExecuteAsync(SqlQuery.CreateDatabase); 
    }
```

My question is, how to write query for creating database and how to ensure, that query completed succesfuly and which method from dapper to use?

My `SqlQuery.CreateDatabase` looks like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'DataBase')
  BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE DataBase
  END
```

Do i need to return something from query?

Comment: Dapper's method **ExecuteAsync** returns an integer value, see what is returning after you execute the query. Your variable (**created**) shouldn't be of type bool.

Comment: Typically, a SQL Server database is created via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). A .NET WebApi would then connect to that database to do CRUD data manipulations. Are you sure that you need to create a SQL Server database via dapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a problem occurs, it should already present as an exception - probably a `SqlException` - telling you about it, so: what you have should already be fine. Note, though, that if your connection string tries to connect to the database *that doesn't yet exist*, then `Open[Async]` is likely to fail. Ultimately, you could just try connecting to the specified database afterwards to be sure, but again, *what you have should already be fine*.

Note that it is often the case that app accounts **do not have permissions** to create databases. In that scenario, you'll need to get a DBA to create the database for you, and tell you the connection details.